# In Excel how do I copy only wanted cells with specific order with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

My code copies the whole thing below last cell by routes now.

I want to filter not only by route but with shipped aswell - so with yes or no.

I also want to copy only selected cells [from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PrmvZ.jpg) to [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6xMso.jpg). like images suggest by the following order (eg. cell C2 to cell A1 in another workbook).

my code looks like this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim cell As Range

With Workbooks("FromHEre.xlsm").Worksheets("Sheet1")

For Each cell In .Range("D1:D" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Row)
If cell.Value = "1" Then

.Rows(cell.Row).Copy Destination:=Workbooks("ToHere.xlsx").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End If
Next cell
End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by no means a complete answer and it's un-tested, but should get you started.

Read the comments and adapt the code to fit your needs

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim sourceWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range
    Dim sourceFilteredRange As Range

    Dim targetWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim targetSheet As Worksheet
    Dim targetCell As Range

    Dim cell As Range

    Dim sourceLastRow As Long
    Dim targetLastRow As Long

    ' Define source and target objects
    Set sourceWorkbook = Workbooks("FromHere.xlsm")
    Set sourceSheet = sourceWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Set targetWorkbook = Workbooks("ToHere.xlsx")
    Set targetSheet = targetWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    ' Get last row of source sheet
    sourceLastRow = sourceSheet.Cells(sourceSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Get last row of target sheet
    targetLastRow = targetSheet.Cells(targetSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Set source range
    Set sourceRange = sourceSheet.Range("A1:H" & sourceLastRow)

    ' Filter source range by route and shipped
    With sourceRange
        .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="1"
        .AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="yes"
    End With

    ' Get filtered range
    Set sourceFilteredRange = sourceRange.AutoFilter.Range

    ' Copy filtered range to target sheet
    sourceFilteredRange.Copy targetSheet.Range("A" & targetLastRow)

End Sub
```